# xCell error of useNames = NA when run rawEnrichmentAnalysis

Tags: r, rna-seq

I am using R version 4.2.0. I have a problem when I am running xCell analysis of RNA-seq data. I tried the

```
rawEnrichmentAnalysis(data, xCell.data$signatures, xCell.data$genes, parallel.sz = 4, parallel.type = "SOCK")
```

(it also happened in xCellAnalysis), then I got this error:

```
ERROR: useNames = NA is defunct. Instead, specify either useNames = TRUE or useNames = FALSE.
```

I also used `IOBR` and `immunedeconv` packages after updated all the packages, both of them gave me the same error(cibersort and EPIC worked well, but I really need the result of xCell).

I think this problem is caused by GSVA package. Could anyone please help me with this? Thank you very much!!

Comment: See if [this](https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/7501#issuecomment-1854571904) works for you.